# Are for a $T_1$ topological space $X$ the following equivalent?

Tags: general-topology

Are for a $T_1$ topological space $X$ the following equivalent? why?

> (1) every sequence in $X$ has a cluster point.
>
> (2) X is countably compact.

Comment: What's the definition of countably compact you are using?

Comment: A space is countably compact if every countable open covering has a finite subcovering.

Comment: I already assumed that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X$ be countably compact and $(x_n)$ a sequence in $X.$ Define 
$T_n=\{x_k\mid k>n\}$. Then the sets $\overline{T_n}$ form a nested family of closed sets. Since no $T_n$ is empty, this family has the finite intersection property, which by countable compactness implies that $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\overline{T_n}\ne\emptyset$. A point $x$ in this intersection is in the closure of each $T_n$ and is therefore a cluster point.

Conversely, let $(U_n)_n$ be an open cover of $X$ without a finite subcover. Choose for each $n$ an $x_n\notin\bigcup_{i=0}^n U_i.$ The sequence $(x_n)_n$ has a cluster point $x$ in one of the sets, say $x\in U_j.$ Then $U_j$ had to contains infinitely many $x_n.$ On the other hand, by construction of $(x_n)$ we have $x_n\notin U_j$ for all $n>j.$ Hence $x$ cannot be a cluster point of $(x_n).$

Answer (score 0):

A detailed argument directly from the definitions:

Suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ has no cluster point in $X$; then $D=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ must be infinite. (Otherwise there is an $x\in X$ such that $\{n\in\omega:x_n=x\}$ is infinite, and $x$ is then a cluster point of the sequence.) Each $x\in X$ has an open nbhd $V_x$ such that $V_x\cap D$ is finite; let $F_x=(V_x\cap D)\setminus\{x\}$ and set $U_x=V_x\setminus F_x$. $X$ is $T_1$, so the finite set $F_x$ is closed, and $U_x$ is an open nbhd of $x$ such that $U_x\cap D=\varnothing$ if $x\notin D$, and $U_x\cap D=\{x\}$ if $x\in D$. Since $U_x\cap D=\varnothing$ for each $x\in X\setminus D$, $D$ is closed; let $W=X\setminus D$. Then $\{W\}\cup\{U_x:x\in D\}$ is a countable open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover: for each $x\in D$, the only member of the cover containing $x$ is $U_x$. It follows that if $X$ is countably compact, every sequence in $X$ has a cluster point.

Now suppose that $X$ is not countably compact, and let $\mathscr{U}=\{U_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a countable open cover of $X$ with no finite subcover. For $n\in\omega$ let $V_n=\bigcup_{k\le n}U_k$, and let $\mathscr{V}=\{V_n:n\in\omega\}$; then $V_n\subseteq V_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\omega$, and $\mathscr{V}$ is an open cover of $X$. If $\{V_{n_1},\ldots,V_{n_k}\}\in\mathscr{V}$ with $n_1<n_2<\ldots<n_k$, then $V_{n_1}\cup\ldots\cup V_{n_k}=V_{n_k}$, so $\mathscr{V}$ has a finite subcover iff there is an $n\in\omega$ such that $V_n=X$; but then $\{U_k:k\le n\}$ would be a finite subcover of $\mathscr{U}$, which is impossible. Thus, $\mathscr{V}$ has no finite subcover, and there must be a strictly increasing sequence $\langle n_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ such that $V_{n_k}\subsetneqq V_{n_{k+1}}$ for all $k\in\omega$. For each $k\in\omega$ let $x_k\in V_{n_{k+1}}\setminus V_{n_k}$, and let $\sigma=\langle x_k:k\in\omega\rangle$. Let $x\in X$; there is a $k\in\omega$ such that $x\in V_{n_k}$, and by construction $x_{n_\ell}\notin V_{n_k}$ for $\ell\ge k$, so $x$ is not a cluster point of $\sigma$. Thus, $\sigma$ is a sequence in $X$ with no cluster point, and it follows that if every sequence in $X$ has a cluster point, then $X$ is countably compact.